# Invalid or unknown request type (not a Dialogflow v1 or v2 webhook request). - Dialogflow CX

Tags: dialogflow-cx

Im using webhook using nodejs/express and I want to send the custom payload to the dialoglow messenger. How can I achieve this as I keep getting error "**Invalid or unknown request type (not a Dialogflow v1 or v2 webhook request)."**

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const { WebhookClient } = require("dialogflow-fulfillment");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request: req, response: res });

  function demo(agent) {
    agent.add("Message from webhook server");
  }

  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set("webhookDemo", demo);

  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.14.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.5.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  }
```

I want to send the custom payload to the dialoglow messenger

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the @google-cloud/dialogflow-cx package. Here you have a start guide: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/quick/api#detect-intent-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

The libraries you are using for fulfillment are for Dialogflow ES version. Dialogflow CX uses v3, but there is no official fulfillment library for that version. You need to build your own Webhook response in a format addecuate to Dialogflow CX using the Dialogflow CX api documentation.

You can find an example for node.js here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3kWOicxmJnE&list=PL41E9cd-QxQ6qouN3HZP0NWMnG4FmIEpN